# Installing native Ruby extensions on Windows for Jekyll

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I'm about to go crazy here so I'll just ask:

How the hell do you install the Ruby Gem Jekyll on Windows.

Jekyll depends on fast-stemmer-1.0.0 and that has to be built as a native extension

I found this handy guide on [RubyDevKit](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit) to install a 'sane' environment on Windows and it works, but fast-stemmer is still hell bent on using nmake to build the binaries and that returns the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>gem install jekyll
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -nologo -I. -IC:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mswin32 -IC:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.
8/i386-mswin32 -I. -MD -Zi -O2b2xg- -G6  -c -Tcporter.c
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'Og-' has been deprecated and will be r
emoved in a future release
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-G6'
porter.c
porter.c(31) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdlib.h': No such
file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fast-stemmer-1
.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.0/ext/gem_make
.out
```

I'm using the nmake that came with Visual Studio 2010 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin as suggested in some other Article. But it still doesn't work.

I've tried running the gem install from the MSYS shell that comes with the DevKit so I do have the Unix make at that point, but I don't know how to instruct Ruby to use make instead of nmake (and reading the mkmf.rb didn't enlighten me either). It's hell bent on using nmake and that fails pretty with the above error message

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**
I finally realized that I had not installed Ruby through RubyInstaller.org. I reinstalled using the Installer and now building jekyll with the DevKit works fine.

Thanks to everyone for pointing that out!

Comment: The include path isn't being properly set here.

Comment: Where do I set the include path?

I updated the question. nmake is actually in VC\bin ..

Comment: You're mixing mswin32 installation with the DevKit which is mingw32. You need a Ruby compiled with mingw32, which is RubyInstaller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a confusion with the instructions you're following. The instructions at RubyInstaller DevKit were created to support installation of extensions using RubyInstaller compiled versions of Ruby.

It is clear, from your current directory (visual studio) and the output of the gem installation you're using `mswin32` based Ruby, which will not work with RubyInstaller or the DevKit we documented.

Please install Ruby and the DevKit from [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) website and follow the instructions there **and avoid mixing with Visual Studio**

Comment: yep looks like you're using an old mswin with the "newer" mingw devkit.  Unfortunately this isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Where does that `mswin32` come from? Are you using the DevKit with the mswin32 port of MRI? The DevKit is only for the current MinGW port of MRI and YARV, it does not work with the mswin32 port (which, BTW, has been obsolete for quite some time now).

If you use the mswin32 port, you are more or less on your own. In particular, you *must* use Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0, because that's what the mswin32 port is compiled with, and later versions of Visual C++ are not guaranteed to be binary compatible. Visual C++ 10.0 (which is what you seem to be using) does not work. Try forcing the platform by explicitly calling `gem install --platform=mswin32 fast-stemmer` or even `gem install --platform=x86-mswin32-60 fast-stemmer`. That way, if the maintainer has provided a pre-compiled version, you don't need to compile it yourself.

If you do *not* use the mswin32 port but rather the MinGW port, try explicitly calling `gem install --platform=ruby fast-stemmer`. And if that doesn't help, try `gem install --platform=x86-mingw32 fast-stemmer`

Comment: Jörg is correct. You're mixing mswin32 installation with mingw32 Development Kit.

For the DevKit to work you need a Ruby provided by RubyInstaller (mingw32 based)

Comment: fast-stemmer do not provide binaries for Windows, you need a working compiler.

Comment: I'm using mingw32 version and still having problems. My output is ....creating Makefile

make
generating stemmer-i386-mingw32.def
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby -e \puts EXPORTS,  + Init_stemmer.sub(/\..*\z/,)\  > stemmer-i386-mingw32.def'
make: *** [stemmer-i386-mingw32.def] Error 258  So it's not entirely a Ruby version problem either but yes you do need devkit to work. I'm pretty new to C/C++ and Ruby extensions are a bit of a mystery yet.

Comment: I just noticed that I put in the wrong version of the devkit too. I had Ruby 2.0 version. I'm going to try Ruby 1.9.3. I'll let you know if that worked in a new comment.

Comment: Okay! Now that I have set up the right devkit and set my path vars manually for %DEVKIT%\mingw\bin fast-stemmer compiles a shared object.